# check os.path.isfile(filename) with case sensitive in python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I need to check whether the given file is exist or not with case sensitive.

```
file = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
if os.path.isfile(file):
    print "exist..."
else:
    print "not found..."
```

TEST.TXT file is present under C:\Temp folder. but the script showing "file exist" output for file = "C:\Temp\test.txt", it should show "not found".

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want `file` to match `c:\Temp\TEST.TXT`, or **NOT** match it?

Comment: What you want is against the OS. In python `C:\Temp\test.txt` and `C:\Temp\TEST.TXT` are *exactly* the same, hence the result you get by `isfile` is correct.

Comment: (because Windows file systems are not case sensitive)

Comment: `os.listdir()` is case-sensitive, though...

Comment: @Bakuriu To clarify that a bit, In Python, on Windows systems with case-insensitive file systems (or other such systems), `C:\Temp\test.txt` and `C:\Temp\TEST.TXT` are exactly the same. This does not hold true in Python on Linux/Unix, where file systems are case-sensitive. In other words, this is a difference in the implementation of the `os.*` library routines on different platforms - not specifically a Python feature.

Comment: @twalberg Yes, but I don't see any problem with that. You are trying to enforce a policy of a different OS on Windows. This is absolutely not a good idea. Python purposefully have different `os` implementations so that you don't have to change your code working with different OSes. By the way: if you want to use posix's path module on windows you can: `import posixpath` then use `posixpath.isfile` instead of `os.path.isfile` (even though I'm not sure if this will work in this specific case).

Answer (score 19):

List all names in the directory instead, so you can do a case-sensitive match:

```
def isfile_casesensitive(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(path): return False   # exit early
    directory, filename = os.path.split(path)
    return filename in os.listdir(directory)

if isfile_casesensitive(file):
    print "exist..."
else:
    print "not found..."
```

Demo:

```
>>> import os
>>> file = os.path.join(os.environ('TMP'), 'test.txt')
>>> open(file, 'w')  # touch
<open file 'C:\\...\\test.txt', mode 'w' at 0x00000000021951E0>
>>> os.path.isfile(path)
True
>>> os.path.isfile(path.upper())
True
>>> def isfile_casesensitive(path):
...    if not os.path.isfile(path): return False   # exit early
...    directory, filename = os.path.split(path)
...    return any(f == filename for f in os.listdir(directory))
...
>>> isfile_casesensitive(path)
True
>>> isfile_casesensitive(path.upper())
False
```

Comment: `return filename in os.listdir(directory)` 1. it fails (as well as `any()` code) if there are both TEST.TXT file and test.txt directory (Is it possible to create them on an ntfs volume programmatically?) 2. It might fail in case-insensitive, case-destroying case (some network scheme).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Indeed; the `any()` was a holdover from the first revision where I had answered the inverse question (i.e. got it wrong altogether). Why the OP wants this is somewhat of a mystery of course.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: For the case-matching directory-plus-exact-same-case-changed-filename case (so `TEST.TXT` file, `test.txt` directory) on NTFS, what would `os.path.isfile()` do for the three possible case-insensitive inputs (exact case-sensitive matchs for file, for the directory, and the 3rd being a case-insensitive match for both but not matching case)?

Comment: my guess – it is an undefined behavior.

Comment: checking by aid of this solution is possible and all fine. However, creating two files with the same sequence of characters is not - not on Windows! One could append a suffix to "test.txt" if "Test.txt" is present before creating "test.txt" and vice versa to create both files - as it is necessary for, e.g., exporting entries of a dictionary for case-sensitive languages (like German: "Abendessen" (noun) vs. "abendessen" (verb))

Comment: @meistermuh: I'm not sure what your goal is; no-one here is talking about creating files. Yes, on a case-insensitive file system you can't create files with the same letters but different case, `Text` and `TEXT` and `text` and `tExT`, etc. are all the same filename on most Windows filesystems (NTFS is case insensitive underneath but the Windows OS adds a case-sensitivity layer on top).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I just wanted to note in case anyone is facing the problem when creating files (like I did) and coming up here via google searching for a solution.

Answer (score -2):

os.path.isfile is not case sensitive in python 2.7 for windows

```
>>> os.path.isfile('C:\Temp\test.txt')
True
>>> os.path.isfile('C:\Temp\Test.txt')
True
>>> os.path.isfile('C:\Temp\TEST.txt')
True
```

Comment: No, too many distractions, you are correct. However, this is *not* an answer; the OP is asking how to do a case *sensitive* test.