# How to resolve case-aware paths in node.js or io.js?

Tags: windows, node.js, winapi, filesystems, io.js

While `path.resolve (myPath)` resolves `myPath` against `cwd`, is there a way to get the case-aware path using `fs` (`.stat` etc.) for Windows?

Actual path casing on file-system:

```
C:\\myProjectX\\aBc\\function.js
```

change dir to c:\myprojectx, then in REPL:

```
process.chdir('c:\\MYprojectx\\abc')
console.log(process.cwd(), path.resolve('c:\\myprojectx\\abc'))
```

Prints`c:\\MYprojectx\\abc c:\\myprojectx\\abc`.

Probably something like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/326153/1712065) suggests for .NET. Note that the other answer on same thread suggests making win32 API call to [SHGetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx) stuct, which eventually leads to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/81493/1712065).

This gives problem when generating data with relative paths, which is supposed to be shared cross-platform.

Comment: `Path.resolve` does not actually touch the filesystem. Does [`fs.realPath`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_path_cache_callback) work for this?

Comment: NTFS *is* case-sensitive, but "the API for file access in Windows applications is case-insensitive, which makes filenames case-insensitive from the application's point of view. Therefore, applications only have access to one of the files whose filenames only differ in case, and some commands may fail if the filename provided is ambiguous." From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity).

Comment: @lxe, `fs.realpath` is also case-agnostic. :(

Comment: just maintain actual path and filenames then use these directly avoiding such calls as path.resolve ?  No ?

Comment: @TimothyGu, yes NTFS is case-sensistive. Even `FS_CASE_SENSITIVE` (in C/C++) flag returns `true`, which doesn't matter when we are making canonical paths (like hand-written resolve function), but it does matter when we want to preserve casing for some *extra-ordinary* use-case. I am sure there is a way in NTFS low-level APIs to retrieve the true casing, which node.js or io.js can consume. Even .NET doesn't have an orthodox solution to this problem.

Comment: @Annie it doesn't seem like the case. As the answer you referenced said, Windows doesn't provide a way to make case-sensitive path. The only way to do that is through manually listing the parent directory and check for a match. This is also the case in [Python on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277566/check-os-path-isfilefilename-with-case-sensitive-in-python). TBH I don't even know why MS cared to make NTFS ["POSIX-conformant"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625) and came up with this half-assed "solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [true-case-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/true-case-path)

```
const trueCasePathSync = require('true-case-path')

trueCasePathSync('/users/guest') // OSX: -> '/Users/Guest'

trueCasePathSync('c:\\users\\all users') // Windows: -> 'c:\Users\All Users'
```

Answer (score 0):

From Node 9.2.0 you can use [`fs.realpath.native()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpath_native_path_options_callback) or [`fs.realpathSync.native()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_realpathsync_native_path_options)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.realpathSync.native('c:\\users') // Windows10: C:\\Users
fs.realpathSync.native('c:\\users\\all users') // Windows10: C:\\ProgramData
```